# Polygon with the same points over and over

Tags: shapefile, c#

I am in the process of reading shapefiles (provided to us by the vendor dealing with GIS products) using a C# program and loading them into a SQL database. I first read the text for the shape and then use that text to update my geometry and geography types. And I am doing this as part of a SSIS package.

My SSIS package failed on one shapefile and threw me an exception:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geometry":  System.FormatException: 24305: The
>   Polygon input is not valid because the ring does not have enough
>   distinct points. Each ring of a polygon must contain at least three
>   distinct points.

After running some manual updates, I found the record that was giving me grief. Then I took out parts of the multi-polygon and ran individual selects on them, creating individual polygons, e.g.

```
SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON(( 118.501323586697 -20.3203577291617, 118.504216161911 -20.3220101539757, 118.502671059623 -20.3212136027048, 118.501323586697 -20.3203577291617 ))', 4326).MakeValid()
```

Finally, I found the polygon that was the problem shape: `'POLYGON(( 118.860739531873 -20.2274797478397, 118.860739531873 -20.2274797478397, 118.860739531873 -20.2274797478397, 118.860739531873 -20.2274797478397 ))'`

I am trying to understand how to fix this so my SSIS package runs and translates and loads my SQL tables without me having to fix up anything manually. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why postgis tag?

Comment: It is a postgis shape file

Comment: **without me having to fix up anything manually**: that seems a bad idea, there is an error in your data. You should fix this manually.

Comment: The problem is that I will be running these ETL packages (on regular basis) that would read the shape files (on a location on the file system), extract the data and load into the database automatically. I can either write some sort of a script task that fixes the data or run a SQL update that somehow finds that problem polygon inside the multipolygon and removes it. That's the reason why there can't be any manual intervention.

Comment: If these shape files are coming from a vendor, and you are finding errors in them, the first step should be to document the error, as you did above, and present it to the vendor to see if they can fix it.  If you are going to continue to use the data, you need to clean it so that it is error-free, instead of trying to find work-arounds for a problem that should be fixed at the source.

Comment: shapefile is a file format from Esri. PostGIS is a spatial extension to the PostgreSQL database. It seems like you are using SQL Server from the syntax. That is another database from Microsoft that has nothing to do with PostgreSQL or the Shapefile format.

Comment: @Nicklas: Thanks for that. As the first sentence of my question begins "I am in the process of reading shape files (provided to us by the vendor dealing with GIS products) using a C# program and loading them into a SQL database." I know what SQL is and a shapefile is. We decided to keep the history of the shapefiles by loading them into the database and as the postcodes and LGAs, etc, change overtime, we can still produce historical reports. And to load these shapefiles, I am using a script task in a SSIS package to read the shapefile data and then load it into the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any ETL process is about digesting data. Somewhere along your path, you are trying to digest bad data.

So how would you write a system that tries to digest, say, a point and tries to load it into a polygon?

Sure you can write stuff to allow to digest it. If it is a point, well, then buffer it by 5 meters! bam! You have a digestable geometry without manual intervention.

*But that is not the point.*

Currently you are thinking of your ETL process as a binary black box for your user ("works" vs "does not work") - and you want the "does not work" to go away.

**This is fundamentally a fallacy.**

Think of your ETL process as a *series of gates* instead. Some things can pass, and some things cannot. That crap polygon you have there, most certainly came from a geoprocessing function or a topology snapping operation where the geometry collapsed onto itself because of some tolerance problem.

**You don't want that in your GIS until it is fixed.**

The gate should stop it, because, trust me, that polygon will cause more problems if it is let inside the rest of your GIS.

My point is that silent failures is most of the time (with some exceptions) a bad approach - even more so for ETL.

Comment: Thanks and I do agree that it should be fixed at source. As I am quite new to this, I was just trying to find out if someone else has seen this and if it is a common issue with these shapefiles. The other question that makes me think is that if I was to use a shapefile directly as a layer for my SSRS reports (as opposed to querying the database for the layer) how does is this bad data handled. I guess I'll just have to create a report to check it out.